# column --table-noextreme

Tags: text-formatting

How does the `--table-noextreme` option of `column` work?

> ```
>    -E, --table-noextreme columns
>       Specify columns where is possible to ignore unusually long 
>       (longer than average) cells when calculate column width. 
>       The option has impact to the width calculation and table
>       formatting, but the printed text is not affected.
> ```

```
$ cat table.md
Lorem ipsum | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem | Lorem ipsum | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut | Lorem ipsum dolor
Lorem | Lorem ipsum dolor | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do | Lorem
$ column -t -s '|' -o '|' < table.md
Lorem ipsum | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet                                                                   | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem       | Lorem ipsum                | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut | Lorem ipsum dolor
Lorem       | Lorem ipsum dolor          | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do                              | Lorem
$ column -t -s '|' -o '|' --table-noextreme 3 < table.md
Lorem ipsum | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet                                                                   | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem       | Lorem ipsum                | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut | Lorem ipsum dolor
Lorem       | Lorem ipsum dolor          | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do                              | Lorem
```

How can I get it to format the table as

```
Lorem ipsum | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem       | Lorem ipsum                | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut | Lorem ipsum dolor
Lorem       | Lorem ipsum dolor          | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do | Lorem
```

(column from util-linux 2.37.2/arch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample data is not triggering the effect of `-E`, probably because no value in the third column can be determined to be "unusually long".

Using this modified sample text:

```
Lorem ipsum | Lorem ipsum dolor | Lorem | Lorem ipsum dolor sit
Lorem ipsum dolor | Lorem | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur | Lorem
Lorem | Lorem ipsum | Lorem | Lorem ipsum dolor sit
```

and a terminal width of 80 columns, I get:

```
$ column -t -s \| -o \| file
Lorem ipsum       | Lorem ipsum dolor | Lorem                                   | Lorem ipsum dolor sit
Lorem ipsum dolor | Lorem             | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur | Lorem
Lorem             | Lorem ipsum       | Lorem
```

(with rows spreading over multiple lines) and

```
$ column -t -E 3 -s \| -o \| file
Lorem ipsum       | Lorem ipsum dolor | Lorem            | Lorem ipsum dolor sit
Lorem ipsum dolor | Lorem             | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
                  |                   |                  | Lorem
Lorem             | Lorem ipsum       | Lorem            | Lorem ipsum dolor sit
```

However, given your expected output, the `-l` (`--table-columns-limit`) option seems to be what you are looking for:

```
$ column -t -l 3 -s \| -o \| file
Lorem ipsum       | Lorem ipsum dolor | Lorem | Lorem ipsum dolor sit
Lorem ipsum dolor | Lorem             | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur | Lorem
Lorem             | Lorem ipsum       | Lorem | Lorem ipsum dolor sit
```

Comment: Note that `--table-columns-limit` was added in version 2.37.